# How to delete orphan files?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'd like to automate cleaning up orphan subtitle files on my NAS which is serving files to KODI.

When I delete a watched tv episode in KODI, it leaves the corresponding subtitle file untouched in the directory.

I'd like to have a Bash script to recursively go through the TV folder and delete subtitle files (*.srt, or sometimes .xx.srt for different language, where xx is the 2-letter language code*) which do **not** have a corresponding .mkv, .avi or .mp4 file.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
-TV
  |-Show 1
  |  |-Season 01
  |  |-Season 02
  |      |-Show 1 S02E01.mkv
  |      |-Show 1 S02E01.srt
  |      |-Show 1 S02E02.avi
  |      |-Show 1 S02E02.srt
  |
  |-Show 2 
  |   |-Season 03
  |       |- Show 2 S03E02.mp4
          |- Show 2 S03E02.en.srt
          |- Show 2 S03E02.sv.srt
```

After deleting episodes it looks something like this:

```
-TV
  |-Show 1
  |  |-Season 01
  |  |-Season 02
  |      |-Show 1 S02E01.srt
  |      |-Show 1 S02E02.mp4
  |      |-Show 1 S02E02.srt
  |
  |-Show 2 
  |   |-Season 03
          |- Show 2 S03E02.en.srt
          |- Show 2 S03E02.sv.srt
```

Comment: You want to delete subtitles or videos? Your input and output don't really agree with each other or with the question

Comment: @muru I *think* the second block is not their desired output - it's showing how some of the `.srt` files have been orphaned?

Comment: @Zanna hmm, but where did that mp4 file come from?

Comment: @muru haha good question!

Comment: Instead of writing `Solved` in the question's title, please mark the answer that solved your problem by clicking the check mark below the answer's score.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop and some tests

```
for f in Show*/Season*/*.srt; do if [[ ! -f "${f%%.*}.mkv" ]] && [[ ! -f "${f%%.*}.mp4" ]] && [[ ! -f "${f%%.*}.avi" ]]; then echo rm -v -- "$f"; fi; done
```

Remove `echo` after testing to delete the files

As a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in Show*/Season*/*.srt; do
    if [[ ! -f "${f%%.*}.mkv" ]] &&
       [[ ! -f "${f%%.*}.mp4" ]] &&
       [[ ! -f "${f%%.*}.avi" ]]; then
         echo rm -v -- "$f"
    fi
done
```

And remove `echo` to really do the job, if you see it is going to remove the correct files...

`if [[ ! -f "${f%%.*}.mkv" ]]; then` means, if there is no such file as the file we are dealing with, that has an `.mkv` extension instead of `.srt`, then do something with the current file.

Comment: `if [[ ! -f "${f%%.*}.mkv" ]] && [[ ! -f "${f%%.*}.mp4" ]] && ...`

Comment: Great! Works as a charm!

Comment: @ICDeadPpl it's great to hear that :)